# Start stream analytics job back in time with reference data

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

Setup: A stream analytics job - We have a stream data in csv format in azure blob storage and reference data in azure blob storage. The query is simple pass through query with a left join on reference data (so if reference doesn’t match the stream data should still output)

Input path for stream data in the job is

> Data/2016/06/08/17/file1.csv

based on the pattern  - Data/{date}/{time} - i.e.  Data/YYYY/MM/dd/HH/

the last modified date of the file is 2016-06-08 16:30:00 - the time we uploaded the file

Input path for reference data in the job is

> Reference/2016/06/08/17/00/ref1.csv

based on the pattern  - Reference/{date}/{time}/ref1.csv 
i.e. Reference/YYYY/MM/dd/HH/mm/ref1.csv

the last modified date of the file is 2016-06-08 16:30:00 - the time we uploaded the file

All the files are in place - when we start the job with custom start time as 2016-06-08 17:00:00.

- we can see the input events but there is no output events
- when we remove the reference data left join in the query - the job produces the output

Note: Current timestamp when executing this job is 2016-06-08 19:00:00 so we are going back in time to process data.

What causes this behaviour?
Why can't we go back in time, start the job and cannot see any outputs? Basically we would like to stop the job - go back in time and replay everything as of that time.

What is wrong with reference file timestamp?

I have also included the last modified datetime of both files wondering whether that plays any role in this behavior.

What are we missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the JOIN condition used? If the time window is large, and not passed. The join might not produce output.

Comment: @Waaghals - left join ReferenceData on StreamColumn = ReferenceColumn. As per the doc Reference JOIN is the only JOIN supported in Stream Analytics where a temporal bound is not necessary https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn949258.aspx